# How to include a second axis in ggplot with another dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 dataframe. The first dataframe is

```
df1
Year        BP
1 1550 -0.004343344
2 1551  0.033794533
3 1552  -0.0034535036
4 1553  0.054935152
5 1554  0.029320574
6 1555  -0.001854373
```

I plot the ggplot for above dataframe1 by :

```
ggplot(df1,aes(Year,BP))+geom_line(aes(color="IP"),lwd=1)
```

Now I would like to add a second y axis on the right hand side corner of that very same ggplot for the below data frame `df2` and also labelled as “second axis”. I want to include variables of CL, PR and NR on that same plot. How can this be achieved in R? Note to serve as an example I only provided 5 years,but in reality I have 100+ years.

```
df2
Year      V1         U   CL         PR          FO   NR
1   1550 7377211     0 0.03615170 0.1405466      0 0.8232772
2   1551 7377212     0 0.03622309 0.1397468      0 0.8240073
3   1552 7377213     0 0.03631065 0.1389448      0 0.8247278
4   1553 7377214     0 0.03639766 0.1381439      0 0.8254495
5   1554 7377215     0 0.03647239 0.1373441      0 0.8261718
6   1555 7377216     0 0.03655438 0.1365248      0 0.8269085
```

EDIT:
This is what I tried so far:

```
f<-ggplot()+ 
geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=Year, y=NBP), color="red")

f+geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=Year, y=CL ), color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.1, 0.2),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . +1, name = "Land Fraction")
  )
```

Is there any to add the PR and NR to this plot?

Comment: Using `sec_axis`, you need to (1) define a transform (often linear), and (2) re-calculate the second-frame data with an inverse of that transform so that its values are relative to the original (authoritative) axis. In this, the second axis is merely a facade, no data is actually based on it. See [`?sec_axis`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) for examples of how to use it.

Comment: This question is a little confusing: your data suggests that you should be plotting all of the first frame's columns, not just `BP`, yet you're ignoring them. If they aren't relevant for the question, don't include them, please. Perhaps you intend to plot one line for each of those columns? If that's the case, the best approach is to reshape the data from wide to long and group the lines. Lastly, your variables' ranges are all over the place, so (for instance) `CL` will be relatively flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking more context, one of the reasons it took so long for `ggplot2` to support multiple axes is that they often occlude or confuse the reader. If not done carefully and clearly, they can suggest things about the data that are not true. I suggest that perhaps a better way to model this data graphically would be using facets

Might I suggest faceting instead?

```r
library(dplyr)   # bind_rows, %>%
library(tidyr)   # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(
  pivot_longer(df1, -Year),
  pivot_longer(df2, -Year)
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ name, ncol = 3, scales = "free_y")
```

[image: ggplot2, faceted]

(I demoed this using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, though this can be done in other dialects of R include base R and `data.table`.)

Comment: I would like to see how BP is being effected throughout 1550-1555 along with the three variables in df2.

Comment: A second axis is not going to allow that easily: the three variables you've shown are very different ranges, and you can only have *one* second axis (it doesn't support more than two).

Comment: I came up with ggplot()+ 
geom_line(data=datalu, aes(x=Year, y=CL), color="red")+
geom_line(data=datalu, aes(x=Year, y=NR), color="blue")+
  geom_line(data=datalu, aes(x=Year, y=PR), color="purple")    how can I add the BP line? I came up with f+geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=Year, y=NBP ), color="pink")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *-0.5, name = "NBP")
  ) but dont know how to set the min and max for the second axis

Comment: You don't set the min/max for the second axis, you set the transformation function (`~ . *-0.5`) and the min/max from the other axis will be translated over. And then *you* have to translate the data (intended for the second axis) into the y-range of the primary axis. Like I said, the second axis (limits, ticks, and labels) are completely aesthetic, no data can be based on it.